# Configuring a build with GTK3?

Tags: configure, gtk3

I have the development libraries for both GTK2 and GTK3 installed on my system.  The `./configure` script only offers a `--with-gtk` flag, and it detects GTK2, whilst I would prefer to build the software with GTK3, if this is possible.  How can I tell `./configure` to use GTK3 instead of GTK2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The APIs for versions 2 and 3 of Gtk+ are different, so software written for version 2 can't simply be rebuilt with version 3. If `./configure` only finds version 2 it's probable that version 3 isn't supported.

I take it

```
./configure --help
```

only lists `--with-gtk`, and nothing like `--with-gtk3`; `./configure` scripts which support both versions of Gtk+ generally use two different options, one for each version.

You could search around to see if a Gtk+ 3 patch is available; there may be a distribution which has adapted the software to version 3...